# Completing a proof for (algebraic multiplicity) $\geq$ (geometric multiplicity)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I have tried myself to prove the following fact:

> If $T:V\rightarrow V$ is a linear operator with two l.i. eigenvectors and the same
> eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $\lambda$ is a multiple root of the
> characteristic polynomial.

---

**Proof**

My reasoning is based on the 3 following claims:

1. there can be at most $n=\dim(V)$ l.i. eigenvectors
2. There are exactly $n$ roots of the characteristic polynomial
3. For every different root of the characteristic polynomial, there is at least one eigenvector that is l.i. from the rest

If these were true, in this situation $\lambda$ needs to be a multiple root. If it were only a simple root, then the characteristic polynomial would need to compensate having other different additional roots to reach the $n$ roots it has. But this cannot happen because they would be associated to additional l.i. eigenvectors, which would exceed the maximum number of them, $n$.

---

I am not sure if I'm clear in the explanation, but I'm myself quite convinced that only these three claims lead to the statement to be proved.

The problem that I see is that claim no. 3 is not completely correct. There is no l.i. eigenvector for a root that's equal to zero. This dismounts my explanation, because the $n$ roots can potentially be filled up by zeros, not necessarily forcing $\lambda$ to be multiple.

Could someone please tell me if this argument sounds robust and if it leads to a complete proof?

Comment: I know there are other questions in the website with proofs for this same fact, but I'm interested in seeing if what I already did goes anywhere, and if not, to understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"There is no linearly independent eigenvector for a root that's equal to zero" - not sure what you mean by this.  If you mean that when eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots$ with $\lambda_1=0$ have eigenvectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots$, then $v_1,v_2,\ldots$ are not linearly independent, then this is not true.  There is really nothing special about $0$ as an eigenvalue.  For a specific example, take say
$$A=\pmatrix{1&2\cr1&2}\ .$$
This has eigenvalues and eigenvectors
$$\lambda=0\ ,\ {\bf v}=t\pmatrix{2\cr-1\cr}\quad\hbox{and}\quad
  \lambda=3\ ,\ {\bf v}=t\pmatrix{1\cr1\cr}\ .$$
The vectors
$$\pmatrix{2\cr-1\cr}\quad\hbox{and}\quad \pmatrix{1\cr1\cr}$$
**are** linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I meant exactly that. I separately attempted to prove my 3rd claim, and I arrived to the conclusion that an eigenvalue $\lambda$ different to the rest, will have an eigenvector l.i. to the rest if $\lambda\neq 0$. Possibly this wasn’t a strong result and didn’t say what happens when $\lambda=0$. In my proof, I divide by $\lambda$, so I excluded the case in which it’s zero, assuming that it wouldn’t apply to it. I have reviewed other proofs and indeed the zero is no exception. This clears up this point but I would appreciate comments about the rest of the proof

Comment: The result follows from the fact that algebraic multiplicity is not less than geometric multiplicity.  You seem to be avoiding this, I assume deliberately in order to get a different proof.  However, if you don't assume AM$\ge$GM then I can't see what is preventing a situation with say $n=3$, eigenvalues $\lambda,\mu,\mu$, with 2 eigenvectors for $\lambda$ and 1 for $\mu$.  This would satisfy your three properties.

Comment: Also can I suggest that sayings like "an eigenvector linearly independent from the rest" could easily lead to confusion.  Linear independence is a property of a *set* of vectors (or more properly, a multiset), not of a single vector, even when "compared" with others.  You should be thinking about a maximal independent set of eigenvectors for each eigenvalue, then putting these sets together into one set and considering whether it is independent.